# Embedding DOCUSIGN Signature Placeholder in PDF Using .net

Tags: docusignapi

Here are the steps in our workflow

1. Using .net we are generating PDF
2. We need to send this PDF to docusign
3. Before sending to docusign, we need to embed anchor tags (like signature) in the PDF which Docusign recognizes.

I am new to DocuSign, please help me how to implement step 3 using .net.

Comment: Are you utilizing an API integration? Or are you attempting to send an envelope from the member console from logging into www.docusign.net?

Comment: This questions seems more of a .NET question than a DocuSign API question.  If you are trying to insert characters or other data into the actual PDFs themselves then DocuSign can not do that.  What the DocuSign API can do is read document content and anchor signature and other tabs at those locations (or at those locations with an offset).  But in terms of generating the actual document content and putting those special strings or markers into the document, DocuSign can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign API does not support PDF generation or modification, so if you are looking to insert special characters or strings into your PDFs that DocuSign can read and use for tag locations then you'll have to do that outside of DocuSign.

Once your document(s) are ready to go into DocuSign, using the [Anchor Tagging](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) feature of the DocuSign API you can place any tab at those locations, and even add an offset if needed.  For instance, the following JSON will place a `signHere` tab 1-inch to the right of wherever it finds the text *Please Sign Here* in the document:

```
"tabs": {
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
    "anchorString": "Please Sign Here:",
    "anchorXOffset": "1",
    "anchorYOffset": "0",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
    "anchorUnits": "inches"
    }
  ]
}
```

Other acceptable offset units are `cms`, `mms`, and `pixels`.